# How can I power a device that requires 5-7V and 2.5-6 mA with what I have?

Tags: power, device

I have voltage pins on one device that outputs 6.23V DC and 70 mA DC. What type of circuit do I have to build that can power up another device that requires 5-7V DC and 2.5-6 mA DC using my 6.23 V source?

EDIT
The source outputs about 60-80 mA current, not 0.1 mA

Comment: Not enough details. The 6.23V already fulfills the 5-7V DC range. What is the rated output current from the device that outputs the 6.23V?

Comment: the second device requires a voltage that is higher than 5V and less than 7V  ..... is 6.23V higher than 5V? .... is it less than 7V?   ................... can the first device provide 6mA of current?

Comment: the 6.23V device supplies 0.1 mA of current.  @jsotola, i thought that was obvious but I wanted to add it just in case it turned out to be important in some way. I suck at designing analog circuits.

Comment: What if the input drops to 5V? do you still want 6V out with more output power than input?  So what is the input max range vs output?

Comment: better to ask then to be sorry ...... one other thing to check: do the two devices have the same ground?

Comment: @jsotola yes, they have the same ground

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist (before i speak, let it be known that I barely know what i'm doing here) if the input (source) drops to 5V, i think it should still be ok since the device i need to power has a range of 5-7V. I don't need a constant 6.23V, as long as its in the range it should be ok. As far as i've observed, it always stays within the 5-7V range.

Comment: Ok a hint on the device would make us wiser. Also what tools are available for you?  ( transistors, Op Amps or >?)

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist the voltage supplying device is a USRP1 by Ettus Research. The device i'm trying to power is the HMC241AQS16 SP4T non-reflective switch by Analog Devices. i'm pulling the voltage from pins on the USRP1 that were intended to power a cooling fan.

Comment: Thanks mobin.  I would think the switch is powered all the time by 5V @ 2.5mA typ  and controlled by anything using 5V logic levels 50uA max and RF Tx is 50 Ohms routed via 4 way switch thru coax at 25dBm Tx levels and -xx ddBm Rx levels on a  PCB with RF connectors  So is it the logic or the RF interface you have questions on because the DC power is separate for both

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist my problem is with powering the switch itself (Vdd). i have a gpio that provides the required voltage levels (logic) for the switch selector pins, it's just powering the device that's the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If* your first device (the "supply") can only provide 0.1mA then you will need an external supply.

5V@6mA = 30mW

6.23V@0.1mA = 0.623mW

30mW > 0.623mW

Energy is conserved.

---

Edit: You have added that the power source is intended to operate a cooling fan. In that case, it seems **much** more likely to be 100mA (0.1A) than 0.1mA. There is still potentially an issue with the ground and also the possibility it may be PWM'd or something like that (since the voltage is non-standard for a fan).

An external 5V supply really seems to me like the safest way to go unless you really need to avoid that.

Comment: No it isn't . It's radiated  +1 for sarcasm -1 for misunderstanding . no comment